# how to use property=value in CLI commons Library

Tags: java, command-line, apache-commons-cli

I am trying to use the `OptionBuilder.withArgName( "property=value" )`

If my Option is called status and my command line was:

```
--status p=11 s=22
```

It only succeeds to identify the first argument which is 11 and it fails to identify the second argument...

```
Option status = OptionBuilder.withLongOpt("status")
                .withArgName( "property=value" )
                .hasArgs(2)
                .withValueSeparator()
                .withDescription("Get the status")
                .create('s');
options.addOption(status);
```

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: I get the values of `p` or `s` using: `commandLine.getOptionProperties("status").getProperty("p");  commandLine.getOptionProperties("status").getProperty("s");`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can access to passed properties using simple modification of passed command line options

```
--status p=11 --status s=22
```

or with your short syntax

```
-s p=11 -s s=22
```

In this case you can access to your properties simply with code

```
if (cmd.hasOption("status")) {
  Properties props = cmd.getOptionProperties("status");
  System.out.println(props.getProperty("p"));
  System.out.println(props.getProperty("t"));
}
```

If you need to use your syntax strictly, you can manually parse your property=value pairs.
In this case you should remove .withValueSeparator() call, and then use

```
String [] propvalues = cmd.getOptionValues("status");
for (String propvalue : propvalues) {
   String [] values = propvalue.split("=");
   System.out.println(values[0] + " : " + values[1]);
}
```

Comment: So the normal way will not solve it ?? I only have to use one of those 2 options...

Comment: As I understood, properties were implemented like properties passing to JVM. In examples such properties often used with option "D", like `-Dprop1=value1 -Dprop2=value2`. The main profit of this style is you can pass a lot of properties, and access to them using one Properties object from single call `Properties props = cmd.getOptionProperties("D");`