# How to use Apache Commons CLI to parse the property file and --help option?

Tags: java, properties, command-line-arguments, apache-commons-cli

I have a property file which is like this -

```
hostName=machineA.domain.host.com
emailFrom=tester@host.com
emailTo=world@host.com
emailCc=hello@host.com
```

And now I am reading the above property file from my Java program as shown below. I am parsing the above property file manual way as of now -

```
public class FileReaderTask {
    private static String hostName;
    private static String emailFrom;
    private static String emailTo;
    private static String emailCc;

    private static final String configFileName = "config.properties";
    private static final Properties prop = new Properties();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        readConfig(arguments);

        // use the above variables here
        System.out.println(hostName);
        System.out.println(emailFrom);
        System.out.println(emailTo);
        System.out.println(emailCc);
    }

    private static void readConfig(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        if (!TestUtils.isEmpty(args) && args.length != 0) {
            prop.load(new FileInputStream(args[0]));
        } else {
            prop.load(FileReaderTask.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(configFileName));
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String arg : args) {
            sb.append(arg).append("\n");
        }
        String commandlineProperties = sb.toString();

        if (!commandlineProperties.isEmpty()) {
            // read, and overwrite, properties from the commandline...
            prop.load(new StringReader(commandlineProperties));
        }           

        hostName = prop.getProperty("hostName").trim();
        emailFrom = prop.getProperty("emailFrom").trim();
        emailTo = prop.getProperty("emailTo").trim();
        emailCc = prop.getProperty("emailCc").trim();
    }
}
```

Most of the time, I will be running my above program through command line as a runnable jar like this -

```
java -jar abc.jar config.properties
java -jar abc.jar config.properties hostName=machineB.domain.host.com
```

**My question is-**

- Is there any way to add `--help` option while running the `abc.jar` that can tell us more about how to run the jar file and what does each property means and how to use them? I have seen `--help` while running most of the C++ executable or Unix stuff so not sure how we can do the same thing in Java?

Do I need to use CommandLine parser like `Commons CLI` for this in Java to achieve this and instead of doing manual parsing, I should use `Commons CLI` to parse the file as well? If yes, then can anyone provide an example how would I do that in my scenario?

Answer (score 2):

In the long run if you plan to add other options in the future then commons-cli is surely a fairly good fit as it makes it easy to add new options and manual parsing quickly becomes complicated.

Take a look at the [official examples](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/usage.html), they provide a good overview of what the library can do.

Your specific case would probably lead to something like the following:

```
    // create Options object
    Options options = new Options();

    Option help = new Option( "h", "help", false, "print this message" );
    options.addOption(help);

    CommandLineParser parser = new PosixParser();
    CommandLine cmd = parser.parse( options, args);

    if(cmd.hasOption("help") || cmd.getArgList().isEmpty()) {
        // automatically generate the help statement
        HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();
        formatter.printHelp( "cli-test [options] <property-file>", options );

        return;
    }

    // do your thing...
    System.out.println("Had properties " + cmd.getArgList());
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was going through the link you suggested but I was not able to understand how to adapt those to my use case. If possible and for my understanding can you provide an example how we would use commons-cli here? This will help me to understand better.

Comment: What is missing in the code-sample I included here?

Comment: What I meant was - how to do use Commons CLI to do the parsing of variables from the property instead of doing it manual way? And also some way to tell people what are these variable names? Like if I do help, then it should tell us what does each variable means?

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18611791/how-to-use-property-value-in-cli-commons-library answers this to some degree. The doc on this is at http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/usage.html#Java_Property_Option